# Datatables internal row count is greater than number of rows

Tags: javascript, datatables

I'm creating a `DataTable` and also using scroller.js so that when a new record is added or a record is updated, it will scroll to the record. The problem is it will not scroll to new records, and I think it has to do with the `DataTable` row counter being off. Here is my `DataTable` initialization code:

```
DataTable({
    dom: 'Blfrtip',
    processing: true,
    paginate: false,
    scrollY: '200px',
    paging: true, // need to have paging true for scroller to work.
    pageLength: -1, // show all records, so we don't actually page
    lengthChange: false,
    scroller: true,
    select: {
      style: 'single'
    }
})
```

I've scrolled to the bottom of the table to show what I think is the problem. I can't show the data, but some of the records have wrapped text columns which it seems to think take up multiple rows despite being one record. Therefore when it adds a new record 50, it scrolls to record 50 which is in the middle of the table as it thinks the bottom of the table is record 92. How can I fix this so it thinks there are truly 50 records and scrolls to the new 50th record? In another function, the columns have their width set to a fixed number of pixels which is causing it to be wrapped.

Screenshot:

[image: Showing 92 to 49 of 49 records]

Comment: Are you displaying the table in a modal dialog or tab? In other words, is it initially hidden?

Comment: No, it's not hidden. I just noticed now the index counter works if I make the window slightly narrower than normal, but not sure why it doesn't work when it fills the screen

Comment: The table is there but data is later loaded. I've removed the static table column widths.